# leading zero dynamically gets removed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have strange validation error

```
public long mobile { get; set; }
[RegularExpression(@"^([09]{2}[0-9]{8})$", ErrorMessage = "mobile number is not correct")]
```

if the user entered 094532415678 it is correct but validation error appears due to the dynamic removal of leading zeroes in asp c# , model will receive the above number as 94532415678 and wont be saved to database throwing error for mobile validation 
I have tried to save it to string and add the leading zero to mobile and save it but still when the string gets converted to "long" directly it removes the leading zero , any solution for this problem

Comment: Do you *really* have that code? Because that doesn't compile.

Comment: The phone number should be a string, not a `long`. Leading zeros in numbers are insignificant and aren't "removed", they just don't exist. There is no numerical difference between `00001` and `1`, in memory or otherwise.

Comment: Phone numbers are not actually numbers.  You cant add them or subtract them, so they are strings where leading zeds *do* matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store telephone numbers (and simular information) as a string. Leading 0's are removed when you save phonenumbers as a number (long).

Comment: then how we will validate the model before submission the form whether user entered mobile number or just any word and number should start with 09 and has 10 numbers

Comment: I'm not an expert on Regular Expressions, but I know these work on strings. Or check in a loop the individual characters.

Comment: @Ebrahim if("...".Where(character => char.IsDigit(character)).Count == 10 && "...".Contains("09"))

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([09]{2}[0-9]{8})$", ErrorMessage = "mobile number is not correct")]
public string mobile { get; set; }
```